# Eclipse Indigo project is not being recognized as a resource in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse

I have a dynamic web project (actually 2 web projects and 1 webservice project) that was created in Eclipse Indigo.

I am upgrading to Juno and Weblogic 12 (from Weblogic 10.3.3). After I pull the project into Juno from SVN and create a new server, I don't have any resources to add/remove. I've gone through all the facets/properties for the project and also the windows/preferences.

I've also looked through the Eclipse help but I haven't found anything that points me to a property that isn't already set. What property needs to be set in Juno or what preferences am I missing that needs to be set?

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: My advice is that you stick with Indigo, Juno has many problems. Secondly, could you give us a screen-shot or something more substantial than "I've gone through this site". Some specific error messages or problems seen would be appreciated when you are attempting to do this.

Comment: Did you check in the .settings folders, .project and .classpath files?

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your project facets properties page with the runtime tab (on the right) visible.

Comment: seems i cant upload the image of my screen because Im not a 10 on this site

Comment: i got somebody with a 10 reputation to post it for me